# Многопоточность в вычислительных задачах

Tags: python, массивы, многопоточность, multiprocessing, numpy

Есть необходимость проведения вычислений по трехмерному массиву. Среди которых присутствуют БПФ и поиск медианы (самые дорогостоящие).

Попытка введения многопоточной обработки дала отрицательный результат по ускорению. При том, что программа даже не производит записи результата (это, предположительно, могло бы тормозить потоки). Видимо, много процессорного времени уходит на оргиназацию потоков.

Есть ли критичные ошибки в организации потоков в программе или для подобной задачи нельзя вовсе получить прирост производительности за счет потоков?

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread
import numpy as np

_size = 256
# создание массива комплексных чисел размерностью 3х3х3 
arr = np.random.rand(_size, _size, _size) \
       + np.random.rand(_size, _size, _size) * 1j

def single(arr):
    # функция, которая выполняется в одном потоке
    for fd in range(arr.shape[0]):
        for sd in range(arr.shape[1]):

            spec = np.fft.fftshift(abs(np.fft.fft(arr[fd, sd, :])))
            amax = spec.argmax()
            val = 20*np.log10(spec[amax]) - 20*np.log10(np.median(spec))

# число потоков
nwork = 4

def multith(arr):
    # функция, выполняющаяся в nwork потоках

    def selffun(arr):
        spec = np.fft.fftshift(abs(np.fft.fft(arr)))
        amax = spec.argmax()
        val = 20*np.log10(spec[amax]) - 20*np.log10(np.median(spec))

    def worker():
        while True:
            item = _queue.get()
            selffun(item)
            _queue.task_done()

    def source(arr):
        # генератор заданий
        for fd in range(arr.shape[0]):
            for sd in range(arr.shape[1]):
                yield arr[fd, sd, :]

    _queue = Queue()
    for i in range(nwork):
        th = Thread(target=worker)
        th.setDaemon(True)
        th.start()

    for item in source(arr):
        _queue.put(item)

    _queue.join()
```

**Результат:**

```
%timeit single(arr)
1 loop, best of 3: 4.61 s per loop

nwork = 4
%timeit multith(arr)
1 loop, best of 3: 7.45 s per loop

nwork = 2
%timeit multith(arr)
1 loop, best of 3: 6.31 s per loop
```

Comment: посмотрите библиотеку numexpr. [Это](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ParallelProgramming.html) тоже может быть интересно. Вы можете показать как собран ваш numpy `print(np.show_config())`? Если использовать `numpy` который использует MKL от Intel то он должен сам распараллеливать вычисления, по-моему

Comment: blas_mkl_info:  NOT AVAILABLE. А в numexpr нет ни медианы ни фурье.

Comment: если вы работаете на Windows попробуйте [эти сборки](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy)?

Comment: @MaxU использую linux

Comment: посмотрите [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/mkl-optimizations/)... [Вот](https://docs.continuum.io/mkl-service/) еще

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Использование потоков не приведет к ускорению кода для вычислений, так как в python есть [GIL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock). Чтобы ускорить код используйте `Process` из модуля `multiprocessing` или `ProcessPoolExecutor` из модуля `concurrent`.

Comment: Спасибо. Потоки в питоне нужны только для задач, где есть ввод/вывод или веб-запросы?

Comment: Да, для задач с io и запросов подходят хорошо.

Comment: И не возникнет ли проблем с записью результатов вычислений в одну структуру данных при использовании процессов вместе потоков?

Comment: Нет, вы же используете очередь. А для случае с ProcessPoolExecutor он вам вернет список. Если вам будет необходимо записывать большой объем данных, то делаете процесс, который из очереди читает данные и пишет в файл.

Comment: ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2): 4.57 s, multiprocessing.Pool(2): 2.78 s

Comment: @mkkik numpy может отпускать GIL, поэтому некоторые вычисления (такие как `A=B+C`) могут быть ускорены за счёт использования нескольких потоков. Cython также прост и удобен для этого (nogil констру). Можно также избежать излишнего копирования, используя общий массив(`multiprocessing.Array`), даже когда несколько процессов используются. Numpy может также omp (не Питон) потоки использовать и устанавливать CPU affinity!! Если есть необходимость ускорить работу кода, то нужно прямо об этом спрашивать (распараллеливание не обязано ускорить код в общем случае вне зависимости от используемого языка).

Comment: @jfs, да, разумеется, нужно ускорение кода. Обо всем вышесказанном где-то можно почитать в систематизированном виде?

Comment: @mkkik: тема необъятная. Не существует одного учебника, в котором написано как ускорить до предела произвольную программу на произвольном железе. Хотя обычно 5% усилий дадут 90% результата (адекватный алгоритм, адекватное использование доступного железа, готовых библиотек), а затем каждый шаг может нетривиальное кол-во усилий потребовать. `numpy` массив это просто кусок памяти с метаданными, позволяющими удобно по ней передвигаться -- поэтому если ваша задача сводится к манипулированию подобных массивов, то можно ожидать улучшений до C/Fortran скоростей...

Comment: @mkkik: ... для начала, [посмотрите пару ссылок, приведённых в конце моего ответа](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25823885/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Это не ответ на свой вопрос, просто хочу написать о результатах, которых получилось достичь благодаря информации, представленной в комментариях к вопросу и ответу. Возможно, это будет полезно для кого-то.

1. **numpy** c **MKL**

   Актуальные версии дистрибутива **Anaconda** включают в себя библиотеку **numpy**, собранную с поддержкой **MKL** и пакет **mkl-service**. Но время выполения моей функции (медиана, БПФ) без распараллеливания осталось прежним (как и без **MKL**). Видел статьи, в которых описан процесс сборки **python+numpy+scipy** специально для работы с **MKL**, но в этом случае необходим интеловский компилятор, который платный.
2. **concurrent** и **multiprocessing**

   При замене потоков на **ProcessPoolExecutor** из **concurrent** без изменения остального кода программы при **max_workers=2** время выполнения приблизилось к однопоточному результату - 4.57 s. При увеличении числа процессов время выполнения увеличивалось.

   При аналогичной замене на **Pool** из **multiprocessing**:

   multiprocessing.Pool(2): 2.78 s

   multiprocessing.Pool(4): 1.74 s

   multiprocessing.Pool(8): 1.3 s
3. **multiprocessing.Process** и разделяемый **multiprocessing.RawArray**

   На основе данного [примера](https://habrahabr.ru/post/167503/).

   ```
   import ctypes, itertools
   import multiprocessing as mp
   import numpy as np

   _size = 256
   arr = np.random.rand(_size, _size, _size) \
          + np.random.rand(_size, _size, _size) * 1j

   def selffun(arr, sl, arrD):

       d = np.reshape(np.frombuffer(arrD), (_size, _size))
       spec = np.fft.fftshift(abs(np.fft.fft(arr[sl[0], sl[1], :])))
       amax = spec.argmax()
       d[sl[0], sl[1]] = 20*np.log10(spec[amax]) - 20*np.log10(np.median(spec))

   def worker(arr, q, arrD):

       while True:
           item = q.get()
           if item is None:
               break
           selffun(arr, item, arrD)
           q.task_done()
       q.task_done()

   def main(arr):

       a, b = arr.shape[:-1]
       arrD = mp.RawArray(ctypes.c_double, a*b)

       nCPU = mp.cpu_count()

       queue = mp.JoinableQueue()

       for item in itertools.product(range(a), range(b)):
          queue.put(item)
       for i in range(nCPU):
          queue.put(None)

       workers = []
       for i in range(nCPU):
          _worker = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(arr, queue, arrD))
          workers.append(worker)
          _worker.start()

       queue.join()
       return np.reshape(np.frombuffer(arrD), (a, b))

   if __name__ == '__main__':
       main(arr)
   ```

**Результат:** 1.83 s (`nCPU = 8`, Intel® Core™ i7-3770 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8 )

Лучший результат по времени получен с **multiprocessing.Pool**, но пока не разобрался, как использовать `Pool.map` c разделяемым массивом.

Comment: отличное сравнение! наверняка пригодится "нампайщикам", работающим с большими массивами данных...

Comment: В данном случае массив данных не большой. И для других задач данный результат может быть бесполезным. Написал для того, чтобы было понятно, с чего начинать пробовать.